# Reading bytes of an Http GET response and printing them while continue to listen for next bytes on the same request

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a system I want to open a socket to, perform basic authentication, send an HTTP POST to register myself and get an ID and then send GET request to a specific URL and start to get notifications.

the thing is that this GET request should have an unlimited timeout and I should fetch and print bytes when they arrive without stopping the request (means that the operation is asymmetrical, its not a request-response operation but a request and an ongoing response where for each byte I should react immediately while keep waiting for the next ones.

for example: I'll listen on such a connection and after 5 mins I'll get "HELLO" on the socket, I'll print it and will continue waiting on the exact same session and after 2 more minutes I'll get " THERE", all on the same session, I want to print the "HELLO" and keep waiting for more input and when getting the " THERE", print it as well and keep waiting for some more data.

can you please guide me how to do it or provide an example code?

10x!

Edit: this is the code I already have, the problem is that after I successfully register I don't get any notifications, means that no callback is being called... I've added a print to verify I do get something before filtering by the identifier but I don't...:

```
import asyncio
import json
import logging
import traceback
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from typing import Union, Awaitable
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from aiohttp import ClientSession, BasicAuth, TCPConnector


class HttpWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, *, hostname: str, global_headers: dict, user: str, password: str):
    self._hostname = hostname
    auth = BasicAuth(login=user, password=password)
    connector = TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
    self._session = ClientSession(connector=connector,
                                  headers=global_headers,
                                  read_timeout=None,
                                  conn_timeout=None,
                                  auth=auth)

    def post_json(self, uri: str, data: Union['dict', 'list']) -> Awaitable[HTTPResponse]:
        return self._session.request('POST', urljoin(self._hostname, uri), json=data)

    def get(self, uri: 'str', extra_headers: 'dict' = None) -> Awaitable[HTTPResponse]:
        return self._session.request('GET', urljoin(self._hostname, uri), headers=extra_headers)

    def close(self):
        return self._session.close()


class NotificationsHandler:

    def __init__(self, hostname):
        self._http_client = HttpWrapper(hostname=hostname,
                                    global_headers={'Accept': 'application/json',
                                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                                    user='user',
                                    password='password')
        self._notifications_identifier = None
        self._keep_running = False
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._log = logging.getLogger("NotificationsHandler")

    async def register_for_notifications(self) -> bool:
        body = { "details": {"register-id": "123"} }
        try:
            async with self._http_client.post_json(uri='register-for-notifications',
                                               data=body) as resp:
                json_resp = await resp.json()
                self._notifications_identifier = json_resp['identifier']
                self._keep_running = True
        except Exception as error:
            self._log.error('Failed to register for notifications: {}'.format(error))
            self._log.debug(traceback.format_exc())
            self._notifications_identifier = None
            self._keep_running = False
        return self._keep_running

    async def handle_notifications(self, notifications_callback):
        """
        handle the notifications
        :param notifications_callback: coro which receives the notification as JSON
        :return: None
        """
        async with self._http_client.get(uri='get-notifications-json',
                                     extra_headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                                                    'Accept': 'text/event-stream'}) as response:
            buffer = b""
            async for data, end_of_http_chunk in response.content.iter_chunks():
                buffer += data
                if end_of_http_chunk:
                    try:
                        update_json = json.loads(buffer)
                        if update_json['identifier'] == self._notifications_identifier:
                        self._loop.create_task(notifications_callback(update_json))
                except Exception as error:
                    self._log.exception("Failed to read update: {}".format(error))
                    self._log.debug(traceback.format_exc())
                buffer = b""
            if not self._keep_running:
                return

    def close(self):
        self._http_client.close()
        self.stop_handle_notifications()

    async def stop_handle_notifications(self):
        self._keep_running = False
```

Comment: You need something like `REST` API which continuously servers the requests.

Comment: *"can you please guide me how to do it or provide an example code?"* - the question just presents a programming task. It does not show what you've tried and where exactly you had problems. It also does not provide any information about the knowledge you have (i.e. do you understand sockets, do you understand HTTP,...). Therefore I propose to close the question as too broad.

Comment: @Krishnachandra Sharma, the question is not on the server side but on the client side.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, you got a point, I didn't want to upload my code because it is quite long and uses internal infra we have here but you are correct and I will add my code to the question